# Sync Algolia Instantsearch.js with Autocomplete.js

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, algolia, instantsearch.js

I have set up instantsearch.js and created an index called `index` which looks like this:

```
{
  "cities": [
    "Boston"
  ],
  "company": "Pineapple",
  "countries": [
    "United States",
    "Canada"
  ],
  "description": "Best pineapple in the world",
  "highlight": true,
  "productTypes": [
    "Hard Drive"
  ],
  "category": "Hardware",
  "title": "Kiwi",
  "objectID": "5"
}
```

I have also set up autocomplete.js and created two indices: `location` and `country`.

This is `location`:

```
{
  "cities": "San Francisco",
  "objectID": "91961120"
}
```

This is `country`:

```
{
  "countries": "Germany",
  "objectID": "92132590"
}
```

I have gotten both functions to work separately, but I do not know how to sync them.

The behavior I'm looking for is that a user can input a search with the help of instantsearch.js and use autocomplete.js to select a location or country to filter down the results. Alternatively, the user can just use autocomplete.js to filter the results by country/location.

I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqbjmO) to show my code. Thanks.

*I know the naming conventions I'm using are not the best, these will be changed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `cities` and `countries` are declared as [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/) in your main index. Then you will need to add the attribute `facets` on the initial `searchParameters` of `instantsearch`. This attribute will contain the name of the facets that you want to use (`cities` & `countries`). From now should be able to apply facet filters on your attributes.

In order to sync both instance you need to listen the `autocomplete:selected` event. You will also probably need to listen for the `change` event on the input and clear the filters when there is no value. For applying the filters you will need to use [the helper](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html), it's the internal library used by `instantsearch` for managing the state.

I updated your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqzmNJ) with the changes explain above.

Comment: Thank you for updating the Codepen as well as your explanation. I'm running into two issues. I don't know how to add countries in addition to cities in the autocomplete:selected event, `search.helper.addFacetRefinement('cities', suggestion.cities).search();` The other issue is the facet acts as AND which I don't want. When a user selects 'Boston' in the facet, and then selects 'Miami', only Miami should be used, not Boston and Miami in the search query. Equally, if Miami is selected and then deleted by the user from the facet, it should be removed from the search query. Can you help with this?

Comment: In order to handle countries & cities you'll need to check which one is present inside the `suggestion` argument and add the according facet refinement. 

For the other issue you'll need to remove the previous (counties & cities) refinements each time the selected value change.

I updated the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqzmNJ) with the changes explain above.

Comment: Thanks boss! I spent a few hours trying to solve it. Your solution works great. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation on here. I'm working on integrating another feature and might need your help there as well if you don't mind. If that is the case, I'll post a new question here. Thanks again!